# Hadoop: Change number of reducers at runtime

Tags: java, hadoop

Assume the following scenario: A set of dependent jobs, which are send to hadoop. Hadoop executes the first one, then the second one that depends on the first, etc. The jobs are submitted in one go using `JobControl` (see code below).

Using Hadoop 2.x (in Java), is it possible to change the number of reducers of a job at runtime? More specific, how can I change then number of reducers in job 2 after job 1 has been executed?

Also, is there a way to let hadoop automatically infer the number of reducers by estimating map output? It always takes 1, and I cannot find a way to change the default setting (except explicitly setting the number myself).

```
// 1. create JobControl
JobControl jc = new JobControl(name);

// 2. add all the controlled jobs to the job control
// note that this is done in one go by using a collection
jc.addJobCollection(jobs);

// 3. execute the jobcontrol in a Thread
Thread workflowThread = new Thread(jc, "Thread_" + name);
workflowThread.setDaemon(true); // will not avoid JVM to shutdown

// 4. we wait for it to complete
LOG.info("Waiting for thread to complete: " + workflowThread.getName());
while (!jc.allFinished()) {
    Thread.sleep(REFRESH_WAIT);
}
```

Comment: I found that value of **mapreduce.job.reduces** property in mapred.xml store default number of reducer jobs.

Comment: You can also do -D mapred.reduce.tasks=yourreducercount

Comment: @SreeVeni, thanks! this would indeed solve the default reducer count problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question. Yes, you can set number of reducers of job 2 after execution of job 1 in your driver program:

```
Job job1 = new Job(conf, "job 1");
//your job setup here
//...
job1.submit();
job1.waitForCompletion(true);

int job2Reducers = ... //compute based on job1 results here

Job job2 = new Job(conf, "job 2");
job2.setNumReduceTasks(job2Reducers);
//your job2 setup here
//...
job2.submit();
job2.waitForCompletion(true);
```

Second question, to my knowledge, no, you can't make Hadoop automatically choose number of reducers based on your mapper load.

Comment: Thanks! I am currently using a `JobCollection` to submit the entire set of dependent jobs in one go. Is there any way of adjusting the jobs after submission? I'll update my question with this info.

Answer (score 0):

The number of maps is usually driven by the number of DFS blocks in the input files. Although that causes people to adjust their DFS block size to adjust the number of maps.

So we can set number of reducer tasks using same logic as map does.
To make reducer dynamic I wrote logic to set the number of reducer tasks dynamically to adjust with the number of map tasks at runtime.

In Java code:

```
    long defaultBlockSize = 0;
    int NumOfReduce = 10; // default value you can give any number.
    long inputFileLength = 0;
    try {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystem.get(this.getConf()); // hdfs file system
        inputFileLength = fileSystem.getContentSummary(
                new Path(PROP_HDFS_INPUT_LOCATION)).getLength();// input files stored in hdfs location

        defaultBlockSize = fileSystem.getDefaultBlockSize(new Path(
                hdfsFilePath.concat("PROP_HDFS_INPUT_LOCATION")));// getting default block size

        if (inputFileLength > 0 && defaultBlockSize > 0) {
            NumOfReduce = (int) (((inputFileLength / defaultBlockSize) + 1) * 2);// calculating number of tasks
        }
        System.out.println("NumOfReduce : " + NumOfReduce);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error(" Exception{} ", e);
    }

    job.setNumReduceTasks(NumOfReduce);
```

Comment: you still need to set this for the job runs, right? This would still require "home-made" scheduling of jobs in a multi-job system. I would prefer giving Hadoop a function that calculates the number of reducers, so I do not have to handle the job scheduling myself.